# Extract Nested Tag Using PHP

Tags: php, html, web

**Tag hierarchy in a webpage :**

```
<body>
   <div id='header'>
      <h2>.....</h2>
   </div>
   <div id='main'>
      <h2>...</h2>
      //Some other content
      <h2>...</h2>
   </div>
   <div id='footer'>
      <h2>.....</h2>
   </div>
</body>
```

**[PROBLEM : ]** From the above hierarchy structure of a webpaege, I want to extract only the **<h2>** tags which are inside the **<div id='main'>**. Can someone please please help me out ?

What I have tried is.... using HTML DOM of php `$h2Tags = $htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('h2');`, but this gives me all the **<h2>** tag which are outside of **main** div as well. Please guide me to a solution.

Comment: You can use an xpath to get more specific with path.

Comment: You should also add what you have tried to the question so other users can modify to the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated this to PHP:

`h2_tags` below will get list of h2s in `main div`:

```
$div_m = $htmlDom->getElementById('main');
$h2_tags = $div_m->getElementsByTagName('h2');
```

This is JS:

```
var div_m = document.getElementById("main");
var h2_tag = div_m.getElementsByTagName('h2');
```

Comment: OP is using PHP, not JS

Comment: **Thank you :)** I made some changes according to PHP, and this works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Where's the update?